# Get row number from two dimensional array with double criteria in different column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
     Name    ID    Date
0    Jhon     2      3
1    Elton    5      6
2    Gonza    8      9
3    Elton    6      1
```

(lets call PrincipalArray this data)

I have this array in a Google Sheet. I get this values to a 2 dimensional array in JavaScript in Google Apps Script.

Then i want to filter something like:
"Number of row who have the name Elton and the ID is 6" --> output is "row 3"

I need this because i need to edit this row when the criteria is true and i need to know the number of row. And if does not exist something with this criteria i need an answer like "-1.00" when indexof can not find something.

I will repeat this search many times, i mean, i need this automated.

I was thinking in something similar like IndexOf but i can just IndexOf first column for Elton and does not exists and "indexOf with two criteria".

In pseudo-code i think this too:

1. Get first column with names   (new 1 dimension array "NamesArray")
2. Get 2th column with IDs  (new 1 dimension array "IDsArray")
3. Filter Array to know how much Eltons are in the array  (length of my For Loop)
4. Loop for with "how much eltons are in array" as length
5. Make indexof in First Column for "elton"  (  NamesArray.indexOf("Elton")
6. Use the result of Indexof in Elton to verify if the 2th column have that ID  in that row
7. iterate..

```js
function asdasdasd() {

  //My data in google sheets
var PrincipalArray = [ [ "Name", "IDs", "Date"],
                   [ "Jhon", 2,  3 ],
                   ["Elton", 5,  6 ],
                   ["Gonza", 8,  9 ],
                   ["Elton", 6,  1 ],
                 ];

//My first criteria to search
var NameToSearch = "Elton"; //will be an input variable by human

var IDsToSearch = "6"; //will be an input variable by human

//Name Get columns from 2 dimentional array because IndexOf only works in 1 dimentional array
           var getColumns = (arr, indices) => arr.map(row => indices.map(i => row[i]));
           var PrincipalArray_Col_Name_2darr = getColumns(PrincipalArray, [0]);         
           var PrincipalArray_Col_Name = PrincipalArray_Col_Name_2darr.map( 
                 function(r) {return r[0];}); 

//IDs Get columns from 2 dimentional array because IndexOf only works in 1 dimentional array
           var getColumns = (arr, indices) => arr.map(row => indices.map(i => row[i]));
           var PrincipalArray_Col_IDs_2darr = getColumns(PrincipalArray, [1]);
           var PrincipalArray_Col_IDs = PrincipalArray_Col_IDs_2darr.map( 
                 function(r) {return r[0];}); 

//Filter the principal array then i can notice how much "Elton" there are
var PrincipalArray_OnlyName = PrincipalArray.filter(function(item){ return (item[0] == NameToSearch); } ); //output expected is 2 rows with Elton Data


//i will start the loop in the faster position
var positionNow = PrincipalArray_Col_Name.indexOf(NameToSearch); //output expected is 2, the first appear of Elton


//I will loop across the PrincipalArray but i will use IndexOf to go faster
for ( var i=positionNow ; i<PrincipalArray_OnlyName.length ; i++) {
    
    //if is equal to "6" the ID of Elton
    if ( PrincipalArray_Col_IDs[positionNow] == IDsToSearch ){
    
              //i will edit that ID and run something here becuase is a match
              Logger.log(PrincipalArray_Col_IDs[positionNow]);

               break; //break because i found the ID with Elton, i edited that and is enough no more things to do and i want go outside of the loop for
    } 
    
         var positionNow = PrincipalArray_Col_Name.indexOf(NameToSearch,positionNow); //output expected is 4 now becuase i am making an indexof starting in the previous step and i will find the next match of "elton"
     
          if ( positionNow ==  PrincipalArray_OnlyName.length ) {
            
            //here i will edit something becuase the ID was not found and i need to know that.
            
          }
}

  
}
```

Comment: Tried `.findIndex()`?

Comment: Hello @TheMaster , i saw about ".findIndex()" but i do not understand how can i create the same idea with FindIndex. Can you help me? is better than my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
//My data in google sheets
var PrincipalArray = [ [ "Name", "IDs", "Date"],
                       [ "Jhon", 2 , 3 ],
                       ["Elton", 5 , 6 ],
                       ["Gonza", 8 , 9 ],
                       ["Elton", 6,  1 ]
                     ];

//My first criteria to search
var NameToSearch = "Elton"; //will be an input variable by human

var IDsToSearch = "6"; //will be an input variable by human

const target_row = PrincipalArray.findIndex(row => row[0] == NameToSearch && row[1] == IDsToSearch) + 1;

console.log(target_row);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! i have one more question, sorry. When is not possible the "double match", it is "6" and "elton", what will return findIndex? is like indexOf which returns -1.00?

Comment: Yes, `findIndex` would return `-1` if no match.

Comment: Nice. Then, why people use IndexOf if have the limitation with array simple? i was making those simple arrays trick to use IndexOf. I can replace those trick and index of with this findeIndex always? seems better

Comment: Both are similar but for different purposes. It is nonsense to compare them.

Comment: But seems like i can do all with findIndex i am right? i see a limitation in indexOf which findIndex does not have. I am just learning if exists some difference it terms of objetive resolving something (not efficiency)

Comment: One 'limitation' of `findIndex` is that it does not work for `string`, which `indexOf` does.

Comment: @idfurw How so? Could you provide a example?

Comment: How is that about findIndex does not work for string? Here "Elton" and "6" are strings, what do you mean?

Comment: When my understanding is correct, I thought that idfurw might have wanted to say that `indexOf()` has `String.prototype.indexOf()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, and `findIndex()` has no `String.prototype.findIndex()` while it has `Array.prototype.findIndex()`. So for example, when `"sample".indexOf("p")` can be used. But `"sample".findIndex(e => e == "p")` cannot be directly used. In this case, it is required to be `[..."sample"].findIndex(e => e == "p")`. If I misunderstood idfurw's comment, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, Tanaike is saying what I want to tell. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Amazing contributions, for real. Then if you work always with arrays is the same thing? but if you have a variable as string, you can not use findIndex right? then if you have a variable as string you can convert that in an array with 1 dimension and work with findIndex?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const principalArray = [ [ "Name", "IDs", "Date"],
                   [ "Jhon", 2 , 3 ],
                   ["Elton", 5 , 6 ],
                   ["Gonza", 8 , 9 ],
                   ["Elton", 6,  1 ]
                 ];
const find = (sKey,sID) => principalArray.findIndex(row => row[0]===sKey && row[1] === sID)
console.log(find('Elton', 6))
console.log(find('Elton',10))
console.log(find('Gonza',8))
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Or as a simple loop:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const principalArray = [
  ['Name', 'IDs', 'Date'],
  ['Jhon', 2, 3],
  ['Elton', 5, 6],
  ['Gonza', 8, 9],
  ['Elton', 6, 1],
];
const find = (sKey, sID) => {
  for (
    let i = 0, row = principalArray[i];
    i < principalArray.length;
    row = principalArray[++i]
  ) {
    if (row[0] === sKey && row[1] === sID) return i;
  }
  return -1;
};
console.log(find('Elton', 6));
console.log(find('Elton', 10));
console.log(find('Gonza', 8));
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Juan Or you could just do a simple loop instead of all maps, indexOf in your question. Edited my answer.